# Why this code does not insert value in database from the form

Tags: php, mysql

This code does not insert value in to the database. I am not able to find any problem in this code. I am new in this era. Please help guys.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    if(!$con)
    {
     echo 'Not Connected To Server';
    }
    if (!mysqli_select_db ($con,'db_name'))
    {
     echo 'Database Not Selected';
    }

    $salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO `db_name`.`tb_name` (`salutation`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES (`$salutation`, `$first_name`, `$last_name`, `$email`, `$phone`);";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
     echo 'Not Inserted';
    }

    else
    {
     echo 'Inserted Successfully';
    }
?>
```

After submit it shows the result "Not Inserted".

Comment: Why do you use backtick (`) instead of quote (') in a query?

Comment: Mmm - SQL injection. Are you trying to build a honey pot for young hackers? If not, throw this away and read a tutorial first.

Comment: @Flying because the OP does not have any knowledge of how PHP or SQL work and is building an efficient way to contribute to a botnet.

Comment: @BoristheSpider indeed, but security is next topic. Looks like he just copy / paste code from some tutorial that was processed by some typographical engine. Of course this piece of code should be thrown away, but you know that query will not work even if there will be placeholders for parameters and prepared SQL statement because column names are also quoted with backticks

Comment: ```$sql= "INSERT INTO `db_name`.`tb_name` (`salutation`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES ('$salutation', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$phone');";```

Comment: @Flying Thanks for your comments, next time I will keep it in my mind and try to make better code....